# Exceptions to "most [relative] properties of subgroups hold in a quotient."

Tags: group-theory

The correspondence theorem for groups asserts that the subgroups $A$ of a group $G$ containing a normal subgroup $N$, and the subgroups of $G / N$ have many properties in common, especially "relative" ones, such as normality, index, the lattice structure.

Wikipedia goes as far as to assert that they have most properties in common, which I take to mean most relative properties (having to do with their relationship with the other subgroups, like the list above, and not intrinsic things like finiteness, or being abelian) are preserved (both ways) in the correspondence.

What are some exceptions to this? What does "most" mean here?

Comment: Residual properties for instance (like being residually finite or residually nilpotent,..);  I think most here is just a "literary" expression.